# plotly plot window resized by legend

Tags: javascript, plotly

I am plotting data via plotly in a 2 window subplot with the ability to switch each plot between a set of 4 datasets. Each dataset has a different number of traces and the traces have different length names. Here is my layout definition:

```
var layout = {

font: {
    family:'Roboto',
    size: 12,
    color: 'rgb(54, 54, 54)'
},
yaxis: {title: "Temperature [C]",
    domain: [0,.49],
    mirror:'ticks',
    showline:true,
    linecolor: 'rgb(54, 54, 54)',
    ticklen:3,
    tickcolor: 'rgb(245, 245, 245)',
    linewidth: 1},       // set the y axis title
yaxis2: {title: "Pressure [bara]",
    domain: [.51,1],
    mirror:'ticks',
    showline:true,
    linecolor: 'rgb(54, 54, 54)',
    linewidth: 1,
    ticklen:3,
    tickcolor: 'rgb(245, 245, 245)'},
xaxis: {title: "Time (your current local time)",
        mirror:'ticks',
    showline:true,
    linecolor: 'rgb(54, 54, 54)',
    linewidth: 1,
        tickformat: "%H:%M"           // customize the date format to
      },
showlegend: true,
paper_bgcolor: 'transparent', //'rgb(245, 245, 245)',
plot_bgcolor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
autosize: false,
legend: {
    orientation: "h",
    y:-.2,
    x:0,
    font: {
        family:'Roboto',
        size: 12,
        color: 'rgb(54, 54, 54)'}
    },
hoverlabel:{
    font: {
        family:'Roboto',
        size: 12,
    },
    namelength:(-1)
},
margin: {
    l: 60,
    r: 60,
    b: 40,
    t: 30,
    pad: 4
},
height: 540,
width: 850
};
```

The issue I have is that as I toggle through the different datasets the legend changes size and that causes my plot window to change size. This behavior can be seen here:

https://youtu.be/OBLgaGd1H0o

Overall, this is visually jarring and not ideal, but I cannot seem to change the formatting to stop the legend from changing size.